# Multithreaded application often hangs with signal 1

Tags: c++, multithreading, signals, posix

I have a application using pthreads and prior to C++11 is in use. We have several worker threads assigned for several purposes and tasks get distributed in producer-consumer way through shared circular pool of task data. Posix semaphores have been used to do inter-thread synchronizations in both wait/notify mode as well as mutex locks for shared data to ensure mutual exclusions.

Recently, noticing a strange problem with large volume of data that program seems to hang with signal 1 received. Signal 1 is basically a SIGHUP, that means hang-up, this signal is usually used to report that the user's terminal is disconnected, perhaps because a network or telephone connection was broken.

Can this be caused because the parent terminal time-outing? If so, can nohup help?

This occurs only for large volume of data (didn't notice with smaller volume) and the application is being run from command line from a solaris terminal (telnet session).

Thoughts, welcome.

Comment: multithreading and C++98 are mutually exclusive. Or at least should be. I could never be sure if the code actually works or I just got lucky.

Comment: Sorry, I meant prior to C++11, edited

Comment: I am using posix thread. C++11 introduced therad as part of the language, but prior to that posix was used, I meant posix, so created thread using pthread_create

Comment: I recommend you read the paper [Threads Cannot be Implemented as a Library by Hans-Joachim Boehm](http://hpl.hp.com/techreports/2004/HPL-2004-209.pdf). In short: Using C++ prior to C++11 with pthreads will at some point create random bugs.

Comment: Are there OS specific thread functions available, similar to Windows CreateThread, CreateSemaphore, CreateMutex, WaitForSingleObject, WaitForMultipleObjects (this one is handy for an atomic wait for both a mutex (onwership) and a semaphore (item present in some form of queue)). I use single linked lists for queued thread to thread messages, but a circular buffer should also work just fine. The queue function interfaces to get (with wait) and append element should be the same for either method or OS. The windows stuff works with Microsoft C89 C compilers.

Comment: Code is working perfectly with small set of data, all synchronizations and mutual exclusions are working as expected, my suspect is the SIGHUP, that may not be anything with thread at all, I am wondering why the signal could come when a long running job is running in a telnet terminal.

Comment: @nwp "There is no such thing as multithreading prior to C++11." Really? I know of a lot of multithreaded applications that were developed considerably before C++11 - using PThreads, or Solaris threads or any number of other threading solutions. It may be true that multithreading was not part of the language standard at that point, but saying that there was no such thing as multithreading is considerably overstating things...

Comment: Yes, that's why I emphasized on prior to C++11, I have been using threads for so many years with prior to C++11 version, on Solaris using pthreads

Comment: @twalberg Your right. I meant to say "There is no such thing as multithreading prior to C++11 in C++ as far as the C++ standard is concerned". Of course people used threads before that, but with no guarantee that it actually works. Basically I said "I advice against using non-standard ways to make threads" in a very lengthy way. Sorry for getting off topic.

Comment: @nwp What do you mean "*with no guarantee that it actually works*"? If you think you have a guarantee with C++11, it's only because the C++11 standard says so, the platform says it supports C++11, and you believe it. You can have that same guarantee without C++11 -- the platform says it supports threads and you believe it. "*Using C++ prior to C++11 with pthreads will at some point create random bugs.*" Unless your platform supports some standard that provides sufficient guarantees like, say, POSIX threads.